# Apache NiFi: how to bind AMQP queue to exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-nifi, amqp

Im experimenting with Apache NiFi and the ConsumeAMQP processor. However it seems not to be possible to create and bind a queue to an RabbitMQ exchange. Am I missing something or is this just not implemented?

The ConsumeAMQP Processor seems to have only some basic settings in the property tab.

[image]

Comment: Not clear what's missing for you. Check doc: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-amqp-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP/additionalDetails.html

Comment: I'm missing a way to create and bind a queue with the autodelete=true flag and not just connecting to an existing one